# Substituir values de um objeto com base nas keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Possuo um objeto com configurações que retornam de um servidor no seguinte formato:

```js
    {
      "example-url": "http://examples.com",
      "example2-url": "${example-url}/examples",
      "example3-url": "${example-url}/ex",
      "example4-url": "${example2-url}/teste"
    }
```

Queria substituir as strings com seus respectivos valores contidos dentro do objeto, ficando desta forma:

```js
    {
      "example-url": "http://examples.com",
      "example2-url": "http://examples.com/examples",
      "example3-url": "http://examples.com/ex",
      "example4-url": "http://examples.com/examples/teste"
    }
```

Como faço para mapear o objeto e dar o replace ?

Comment: A minha primeira pergunta é: O servidor tem mesmo de retornar esse resultado? qual é a razão por trás dessa lógica? podes mudar o servidor?

Comment: @Sergio Sim, o servidor precisa retornar o objeto neste formato, pois ele é utilizado em outras aplicações. Foi feito desta forma, pois ele é um Spring Cloud Config e no Java ele já resolve automaticamente estes nomes.

Comment: Presumo que faltem `"` no teu objeto inicial, ambas as respostas em baixo tomaram esse pressuposto.

Comment: Corrigido, @Sergio. Obrigado pelo apontamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usando replace nos valores das keys usando um laço `for`:

```js
const obj = {
      "example-url": "http://examples.com",
      "example2-url": "${example-url}/examples",
      "example3-url": "${example-url}/ex",
      "example4-url": "${example2-url}/teste"
    }

for(let item in obj){
   // pega o que estiver dentro de ${} com regex
   let url = obj[item].match(/\${(.+?)}/);
   // faz o replace pelo valor da key se encontrou o padrão da regex acima
   if(url) obj[item] = obj[item].replace('${'+url[1]+'}', obj[url[1]]);
}
    
console.log(obj);
```